# What is this aircraft on the grass in Budapest International Airport?

Tags: airliner, airport, aircraft-identification

[image: the aircraft as seen on google maps]

While taxiing after landing in BUD recently, I noticed a widebody aircraft half-hidden in the trees on the grass of the airport. You can see it on Google Maps [over here](https://goo.gl/maps/ar2JguPxsApZiwPY9).

What is this aircraft, and why is it positioned like that? There’s the fire brigade building nearby, but they already have a training aircraft a lot nearer.

More 3D views:
[image][image][image]

Comment: I added some 3D views to help with identification. Someone should be able to easily find out from them once my edit is peer reviewed.

Comment: Is there some usual reason why its vertical stabilizer would be missing?

Comment: @Roger as per the first photo in DeepSpace’s answer, the vertical stabilizer is missing because it’s on display in the nearby museum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has the distinct shape of the 767, and it is indeed a 767 (registration [HA-LHB](https://planespotters.net/airframe/Boeing/767/HA-LHB-Malev-Hungarian-Airlines/L9PYibd8), ex Malev) as can be seen in these photos:

- https://www.airliners.net/photo/Malev-Hungarian-Airlines/Boeing-767-27G-ER/4847571
- https://www.airliners.net/photo/Untitled-Malev-Hungarian-Airlines/Boeing-767-27G-ER/4850697
- https://www.airliners.net/photo/Untitled-Malev-Hungarian-Airlines/Boeing-767-27G-ER/4808155

By the state of the airframe (and the fact that it is illuminated) it is indeed looks like it is being used as a firefighting/rescue training frame.

Comment: It’s interesting that they would put it so far from the fire brigade building though. You have to go through or around  the patch of trees to get to the aircraft — there doesn’t seem to be a pathway to it.

Comment: @mcm69 - that might well be the purpose - in real emergency situations there won't be a nice easy path to the site, so one should train for it not to be easy.

Comment: At one of the airports I frequent (I forgot which one, it might be Frankfurt, Oslo, Bergen, or Lisbon), the firefighting training mockup sits right next to one end of one of the runways. Which means that during training, the last thing a nervous passenger is going to be see before leaving safe ground, is an airplane going up in a giant fireball right next to them. Might be another reason to put it out of sight.